# Using Let's encrypt with Apache and Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, lets-encrypt

On same machine is running Apache on port 80 and Tomcat on port 8080.

Apache include html;css;js; files and make calls to tomcat services.

Basically *exampledomain.com* calls *exampledomain.com:8080* to receive data.

Now i upgraded the protocol from http to https using Let's Encrypt certbot to generate the certificate, this certificate will be updated every 3 months by certbot. Apache is running fine on port 443 but Tomcat still use port 8080, i can use same certificate to run tomcat on port 8443 but.. for doing this the certificate needs to be converted to Java Keystore.

My question is, if i will convert the certificate it will expire after 3 month and i need to convert the new generated certificate by certbot to Java Keystore again ?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you have to convert the certificate every time it expires.**

Tomcat accept .jks and .pfx certificates and you can make it easy to autoconvert everytime certbot generates new certificate by writing a script and make it run with certbot renewal-hooks.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adjust these variables as necessary

# Where you want to final PKCS12 file to be stored.
CERT_PATH="/opt/app/certificate.pfx"

# Password to encrypt the PKCS12 file.
CERT_PW="ShoobyDooby"

# Path to LE files, RENEWED_LINEAGE provided by CertBot
PRIV_KEY_PEM="$RENEWED_LINEAGE/privkey.pem"
CERT_PEM="$RENEWED_LINEAGE/cert.pem"
CHAIN_PEM="$RENEWED_LINEAGE/chain.pem"

# If there's already a .pfx file, back it up
if [[ -f "$CERT_PATH" ]]; then
    now=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%T`
    mv $CERT_PATH $CERT_PATH.bak.$now
fi

# Le Conversion
openssl pkcs12 -export -out $CERT_PATH -inkey $PRIV_KEY_PEM -in $CERT_PEM -certfile $CHAIN_PEM -password pass:$CERT_PW
```

Place this script in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/auto_pfx.sh

Don't forget to `chmod!` If the script isn't executable, it's ignored.

[Automatic PKCS12 Conversion for Let's Encrypt Certificates](https://github.com/StormWindStudios/OpenSSL-Notes/blob/master/letsencrypt_autopfx.md)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no:

- **yes**, if you want to keep your certificate in PKCS12 or JKS format, you'll have to convert it after every renewal, like in your answer,
- **no**, converting to PKCS12 is not necessary on any supported version of Tomcat, except 7.0 (which reaches end-of-life in two months anyway). Tomcat 8.5, 9.0 and the upcoming 10.0 have no problem reading PEM-encoded certificates, just configure it like this:

```xml
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem"
                 certificateFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/cert.pem"
                 certificateChainFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/chain.pem"
                 type="RSA" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

This works on all three types of connector (NIO, NIO2 and APR). On the other hand the APR connector never supported PKCS12 and JKS keystores.