# Tomcat, OpenSSL, SSL error with keytool: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, openssl, keytool

I need help, first of all, in any of stackoverflow posts I can't found a correct answer.

I'm tring to set my Web application in tomcat server with SSL using **Keytool** and **Certbot**
First I used Certbot and generated the respectives .pem files (privkey.pem, fullchain.pem, etc).
After that I did this steps:

Add with OpenSSL my privkey.pem to JKS
[image: Adding privkey.pem to JKS with OpenSSL]

**My password is too simple "123456", impossible to forget. (I'm just trying)**
After that I convert the pkcs12 to JKS with:
[image: Convert pkcs12 To JKS]

Finally Add the chain.pem to my Keystore. In this step I enter the password that I entered previously. And I get the meesage:

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

[image: Adding the chain.pem to keystore]

If I edit my server.xml file in Tomcat server with connector 8443 and my keystore, when I start server I get the same error in catalina.out.

Comment: Please include those commands as text, not as image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Let's encrypt with Apache and Apache Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902583/using-lets-encrypt-with-apache-and-apache-tomcat)

Comment: I upload image to see the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password of your `MyDSKeyStore.jks` file is *'-destkeypass'*, as a consequence of the way **keytool** parses the second commandline you used: `-deststorepass` should be followed be the password. In your case it is followed by `-destkeypass`.

**Remark:** Your question seems to be na [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you want to configure a Tomcat SSL connector using certificates in PEM format, so you ask how to transform a PEM certificate into JKS. While the procedure you show is almost correct, it is useless on modern Tomcat's (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65906950/11748454)): Tomcat supports PKCS12 files since version 5.5 at least and supports certificates in PEM format since version 8.5. There is no need to convert anything.

Comment: I did the answer that you talk about before, but I didn't get results, therefoe I decided to use this method

Comment: You should check your logs, probably you had a problem with file permissions (the private key is by default only readable by `root`, while Tomcat runs as another user).

Comment: I did chmod 700 and 777 for /etc/letsencrypt/live/ and nothing, my catalina.out doesn't show me any error message =(

Comment: If `Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]` is not followed by `Failed to start component...` then everything went fine. Remark: `/etc/letsencrypt/live` is mostly symbolic links, the permissions that matter are those on `/etc/letsencrypt/archive`.

Comment: Thanks for all you get me a lot of information that was so useful to get it!